# Using ui-router to simply launch a function without changing state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-translate

I have a LanguageSwitcher service and a LanguageSwitcher.switchLanguage() function that I can use to switch Language between french and english.

I am now trying to use a ui-router state to execute that function and it seems to work because I can see a 'translated' class (it toggles between 'french' and 'english') change in the markup when inspecting BUT the page goes blank like it's trying to load a view that is not there or something.

So I would like to prevent this behaviour and simply execute the function 'without changing the state' if possible.

```
<a ui-sref="language">Toggle</a>
```

Here is the ui-router config:

```
'use strict';

(function() {
    angular.module('frontApp')
        .run(['$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams', function($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {
            $rootScope.$state = $state;
            $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
        }]
    )
    .config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider', '$locationProvider', function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider, $locationProvider){
        $urlRouterProvider
            .otherwise('/');
        $stateProvider
            .state('home', {
                url: '/',
                templateUrl: '/views/home.html',
                controller: 'HomeCtrl'
            })
            .state('home.rules', {
                url: '^/rules',
                templateUrl: '/views/rules.html'
            })
            .state('home.terms', {
                url: '^/terms',
                templateUrl: '/views/terms.html'
            })
            .state('home.faq', {
                url: '^/faq',
                templateUrl: '/views/faq.html'
            })
            .state('language', {
                controller: ['LanguageSwitcher', function(LanguageSwitcher) {
                    LanguageSwitcher.switchLanguage();
                }]
            });
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    }]);
}());
```

This is because my menu is dynamic and the toggle is not the last item of the navbar:

```
<header ng-controller="NavbarCtrl">
    <h1><a class="navbar-brand" ui-sref="home">{{ 'siteTitle' | translate }}</a></h1>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li ng-repeat="item in menu" ui-sref-active="active">
            <a ui-sref="{{item.state}}" ng-href="{{item.link}}">{{item.title}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</header>
```

The navbar.js file:

```
'use strict';

(function() {
    angular.module('frontApp').controller('NavbarCtrl', ['$scope', '$translate', '$location', '$rootScope', function ($scope, $translate, $location, $rootScope) {
        $rootScope.$on('$translateChangeSuccess', function () {
            $translate(['linkHome', 'linkRules', 'linkTerms', 'linkFAQ', 'language', 'otherLanguage', 'linkMainSite']).then(function (translations) {
                $scope.menu = [
                    {
                        'title': translations.linkHome,
                        'link': '/',
                        'state': 'home'
                    },
                    {
                        'title': translations.linkRules,
                        'link': '/rules',
                        'state': 'home.rules'
                    },
                    {
                        'title': translations.linkTerms,
                        'link': '/terms',
                        'state': 'home.terms'
                    },
                    {
                        'title': translations.linkFAQ,
                        'link': '/faq',
                        'state': 'home.faq'
                    },
                    {
                        'title': translations.language,
                        'link': '/'+translations.otherLanguage,
                        'state': 'language'
                    },
                    //{
                    //    'title': translations.linkMainSite,
                    //    'link': 'http://'+translations.linkMainSite,
                    //    'state': ''
                    //}
                ];
                //$scope.isActive = function(route) {
                //   return route === $location.path();
                //};
            });
        });
    }]);
}());
```

What I am missing? Many thanks for your time and help.

Comment: `trying to load view that's not there`... that's exactly it, there is no template associated for it to  load the way you have it configured

Comment: @charlietfl What should I do then to obtain the behaviour I wish?

Comment: can't you just call the `LanguageSwitcher.switchLanguage()` from another controller?

Comment: @charlietfl I updated the question with more infos to explain why I want to do this.

Comment: what about using `ng-if` inside the menu repeater? Then instead of href's have `ng-click` for language

Comment: @charlietfl ohhh :-) let me try ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the problem being how to use `ng-repeat` for the menu links, one suggestion would be using `ng-if` to create a different link for `language` that uses `ng-click` to manage the switching and not set any `href` attributes for it

Something like

```
<li ng-repeat="item in menu" ui-sref-active="active">
    <a ng-if="item.state !== 'language'" ui-sref="{{item.state}}" ng-href="{{item.link}}">{{item.title}}</a>
    <a ng-if="item.state === 'language'" ng-click="switchLang()">{{item.title}}</a>
</li>
```

Then in NavbarCtrl controller have `switchLang()` make the call to your language service

Comment: Great thanks! There a quote missing after language but then it works great. I'm learning to program, sometimes I don't have the right thinking but many thanks for your time and help.

Comment: np..oops on typo, hate writing code in this environment

Answer (score 0):

This is inferred in many of the comments from your post: there is no reason to use a state to call the language switcher.

Instead you probably just want to include the controller in your menu using ng-controller, or create a component/directive, and call the service method through the using ngClick.